# Java GridBagLayout - disable vertical fill

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I'm having a problem with vertical filling in my GridBagLayout-GUI. Here is the Code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Spielklasse {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JPanel page = new JPanel();
    page.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        JPanel subPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setText("label " + i + ":");
        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120,20));

        subPanel.add(label, BorderLayout.WEST);
        subPanel.add(textField, BorderLayout.EAST);

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = i;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 20, 10, 20);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        page.add(subPanel, c);
    }

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(page);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(300,500);
    frame.add(scrollPane);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

I want to have label+textfield directly under the previous ones without filling the vertical space between (like when you resize my example vertically till you can see the vertical scrollbar). How can I achieve that? With my code the whole panel is filled vertically, but I don't want this.

Comment: **Don't** use `setPreferredSize()` method at all.

Comment: By the way, you might want to use `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` so that you don't accidentally launch a billion JVMs while testing.

Comment: As mentionned, `setPreferredSize()` shouldn't be used. Use the [JTextfield constructor specifying columns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#JTextField%28int%29) instead if you need fixed size.

Comment: Don't using setPreferredSize() doesn't help. @Jeff Gohlke: Thanks, I always wondered why so many JVM's were running :)

Comment: @user3418986 I've fallen into that trap many times myself. :)  Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove next line `c.weighty = 1;`.

Read more in [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#weighty).

Edit: use dummy `JLabel` for grabbing free space, after loop:

```
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 5;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
c.weightx=1;
c.weighty=1;
c.gridwidth = 2;
page.add(new JLabel(" "),c);
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem but creates a new one, now everything is centered. But i want to have everything on Top of the panel.

Comment: @user3418986 Please add to your question exactly what you want the resulting UI to look like, since we could go on for a while if you add new requirements in comments. Add everything to the question so the answer is actually complete.

Answer (score 1):

I made a few changes to your code.

1. Always start a Swing application with a call to the SwingUtilities invokeLater method.  This puts the Swing components on the [Event Dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
2. Since you're using the GridBagLayout, you can lay out your labels and text fields directly on the page JPanel.
3. I created a GridBagConstraints for each label and text field.  That way, we're not relying on defaults.  We specify the correct anchor and fill values for each component.
4. I added a couple of missing JFrame methods.  You either have to specify a default close operation, or you have to close the application yourself.  Without this specification, your application will continue to run after you close the main JFrame.

Edited to add:

1. To get the effect you want, put your page JPanel inside another JPanel.  The outside JPanel has the FlowLayout.

Here's the modified code.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Spielklasse implements Runnable {

    private static final Insets baseInsets = 
            new Insets(10, 20, 10, 20);

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JPanel page = new JPanel();
        page.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        int gridy = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel();
            label.setText("Label " + i + ":");
            addComponent(page, label, 0, gridy, 
                    1, 1, baseInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, 
                    GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

            JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
            addComponent(page, textField, 1, gridy++, 
                    1, 1, baseInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, 
                    GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);
        }

        mainPanel.add(page);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(mainPanel);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Spielklasse");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addComponent(Container container, Component component,
            int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight, 
            Insets insets, int anchor, int fill) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(gridx, gridy,
                gridwidth, gridheight, 1.0D, 1.0D, anchor, 
                fill, insets, 0, 0);
        container.add(component, gbc);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Spielklasse());

    }

}
```

Comment: There might be a good reason, not mentionned, that he wants them in a separate panel (ease of removing them is one but there's others).

Comment: @Jonathan Drapeau: Fine.  Then don't complain about how it looks visually.

Comment: Thanks for your tips, but the problem remains here :) when you resize the frame vertically, vertical space between label+textfield is created.

Comment: @user3418986: Modified the code to eliminate vertical space.

Comment: @user3418986 `Thanks alot, now everything works fine` If this answer helped you solve your problem, then help everyone out and mark it as correct. This will prevent the other volunteers here from reading a question and sifting through code if the answer has already been supplied.